# @JsonProperty() y @JsonSetter() Para cambiar el "nombre" de la clave

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un servicio en java el cual me devuelve un json de OTRO servicio rest tal que así:

```
[
 {
   "nombre":"edu",
   "apellido": "bw"
 }
]
```

Así obtengo los datos

```
LinkedHashMap list =  this.restTemplate.
                getForObject(this.urlBase + this.url , LinkedHashMap.class);
```

Y ahora uso un mapper para transformar ese hashmap a mi objeto java:

```
List<Persona> list2 = new ArrayList<Persona>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

list2.add(mapper.convertValue(list2 , Persona.class));
```

En la clase Java:

```
public class Persona implements Serializable{

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

}
```

Entonces ahora yo quiero que al enviar los datos, el json cambie a:

```
 [
     {
       "name":"edu",
       "surname": "bw"
     }
 ]
```

Estoy Intentando sin ningún éxito poner:

```
   @JsonProperty("name")
   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre= nombre;
    }

   @JsonSetter("name")
   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre= nombre;
    }
```

También he probado con los @JsonGetter ... en los métodos get de la clase java y SIEMPRE obtengo null...

Alguno puede decir... pues te haces otra clase JAVA con los campos en inglés y es la que envías... pero el problema es que hablamos de más de 1Millón de usuarios con cientos de campos y tardaría la vida recorrer el List principal y pasarlo al otro array ....

Gracias.

Comment: Has tratado colocar el `@JsonProperty("name")` justo sobre `private String nombre;` en tu clase `Persona`?

Comment: Sí, y el problema con eso es que cuando recoge los datos del otro servicio web, esos datos se llaman "nombre" y no "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He notado que en tu ejemplo, la anotacion de `@JsonProperty` la estas usando en el Setter, y no en el getter o la definicion de la variable privada

Deberias poder conseguir tu objetivo con una de las siguientes dos maneras.

Utilizando `JsonProperty`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Persona implements Serializable{
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String nombre;

    ...
}
```

Utilizando `JsonGetter`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;

public class Persona implements Serializable{
    private String nombre;

    ...

    @JsonGetter("name")
    public void getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre= nombre;
    }

    ...
}
```